# Problem referencing redux store, state & context of nested component routes in react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, use-state, react-context

There is a Catalogue component that some redux store & react context provider code. Before router v6, they wrapped a nested `<BrowserRouter>` containing Catalogue child routes like below

### BEFORE

**client/src/components/Catalogue/index.js**

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";

import { getPeopleBy, getChaptersBy, getPostsBy } from "../../api"
import playlistReducer from "../../store/reducers/playlists";

import SideBar from "../CatalogueSidebar/SideBar";
import CatalogueHeader from "../CatalogueHeader/CatalogueHeader"

import CatalogueHome from "../CatalogueHome/CatalogueHome";
import CatalogueSearch from "../CatalogueSearch";
import People from "../People/People";
import Chapters from "../Chapters/Chapters";
import Posts from "../Posts/Posts";
import PostDetail from "../PostDetail/PostDetail";

import FooterBar from "../FooterBar/FooterBar";
import style from "./Catalogue.module.css"

const Catalogue = () => {

  const [chapters, setChapters] = useState(null)
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(null)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)

  const fetchCatalogue = async () => {
    let chapters = await getChaptersBy("latest")
    let people = await getPeopleBy("active")
    let posts = await getPostsBy("recently_added")

    return { chapters, people, posts }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      document.documentElement.className = ""; //<head>
      document.body.className = style.CatalogueBody; //<body>

      fetchCatalogue().then(response => {

        setChapters(response.chapters)
        setPeople(response.people)
        setPosts(response.posts)
      })
      return () => {
        setChapters(null)
        setPeople(null)
        setPosts(null)
      }
  }, [])

  const reducers = combineReducers({
      chapters: playlistReducer,
      people: playlistReducer,
  });
  
  const store = createStore(reducers);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className={style.App}>
        <Router>
          <SideBar />
          <CatalogueHeader account={{display_name: "User"}}/>
          <Route path="/catalogue" exact>
            <CatalogueHome chapters={chapters} people={people} posts={posts}/>
          </Route>   
          <Route path="/catalogue/search">
            <CatalogueSearch />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/catalogue/posts">
            <Posts/>
          </Route>   
          <Route path="/catalogue/posts/:id">
            <PostDetail />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/catalogue/people">
            <People />
          </Route> 
          <Route path="/catalogue/chapters">
            <Chapters />
          </Route> 
        </Router>
        <FooterBar />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts,
    people: state.people,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    initPosts: (data) => dispatch({ type: "init", posts: data }),
    initPeople: (data) => dispatch({ type: "init", people: data }),
  };
};

export default Catalogue;
```

**client/src/components/App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import TierA from "./TierA"
import TierB from "./TierB"
import Catalogue from "./Catalogue"
import Admin from "./Admin"
import NotFound from "./NotFound"

import PlayerContext from "./Player/context"
import SearchContext from "./Search/context"
import CatalogueSearchContext from "./CatalogueSearch/context"
import { useSearch } from "../hooks/useSearch"

const App = () => {

    const searchText = useSearch()
    const [playerItem, setPlayerItem] = useState(null)

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <SearchContext.Provider value={searchText}>
        <CatalogueSearchContext.Provider value={searchText}>
        <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ playerItem, setPlayerItem }}>
            <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route component={TierA} exact path="/tier_a" />
                    <Route component={TierB} exact path="/tier_b" />
                    <Route component={Catalogue} path="/catalogue" />
                    <Route component={Admin} path="/admin" />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </PlayerContext.Provider>
        </CatalogueSearchContext.Provider>
        </SearchContext.Provider>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}


export default Routes;
```

### AFTER

Updated `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"` to `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"`, and catalogue routes have a few problems. Moved the `Catalogue` child components to `App` but only kept `CatalogueHome` which will be rendered for catalogue index `"/"`

**client/src/components/Catalogue/index.js**

```
 import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";

import { getPeopleBy, getChaptersBy, getPostsBy } from "../../api"
import playlistReducer from "../../store/reducers/playlists";
import playingReducer from "../../store/reducers/playing";

import SideBar from "../CatalogueSidebar/SideBar";
import CatalogueHeader from "../CatalogueHeader/CatalogueHeader"

import CatalogueHome from "../CatalogueHome/CatalogueHome";
import CatalogueSearch from "../CatalogueSearch";
import Posts from "../Posts/Posts";
import PostDetail from "../PostDetail/PostDetail";
import People from "../People/People";
import Chapters from "../Chapters/Chapters";

import FooterBar from "../FooterBar/FooterBar";
import style from "./Catalogue.module.css"

const Catalogue = () => {

  const [chapters, setChapters] = useState(null)
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(null)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)

  const fetchCatalogue = async () => {
    let chapters = await getChaptersBy("latest")
    let people = await getPeopleBy("active")
    let posts = await getPostsBy("recently_added")

    return { chapters, people, posts }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      document.documentElement.className = ""; //<head>
      document.body.className = style.CatalogueBody; //<body>

      fetchCatalogue().then(response => {

        setChapters(response.chapters)
        setPeople(response.people)
        setPosts(response.posts)
      })
      return () => {
        setChapters(null)
        setPeople(null)
        setPosts(null)
      }
  }, [])

  const reducers = combineReducers({
      chapters: playlistReducer,
      people: playlistReducer,
  });
  
  const store = createStore(reducers);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className={style.App}>

          <SideBar />
          <CatalogueHeader account={{display_name: "User"}}/>

           <CatalogueHome chapters={chapters} people={people} posts={posts}/>

        <FooterBar />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts,
    people: state.people,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    initPosts: (data) => dispatch({ type: "init", posts: data }),
    initPeople: (data) => dispatch({ type: "init", people: data }),
  };
};

export default Catalogue;
```

The new App.js does not have absolute paths for `"catalogue"`, so it is using react router v6 and `<Outlet/>`, but it is missing all of the redux & context wrappers it needs to reference:
**client/src/components/App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import TierA from "./TierA"
import TierB from "./TierB"
import Catalogue from "./Catalogue"

import CatalogueHome from "./CatalogueHome/CatalogueHome";
import CatalogueSearch from "./CatalogueSearch";
import Chapters from "./Chapters/Chapters";
import PostDetail from "./PostDetail/PostDetail";
import People from "./People/People";
import Posts from "./Posts/Posts";

import Admin from "./Admin"
import NotFound from "./NotFound"

import PlayerContext from "./Player/context"
import SearchContext from "./Search/context"
import CatalogueSearchContext from "./CatalogueSearch/context"
import { useSearch } from "../hooks/useSearch"


const App = () => {

    const searchText = useSearch()
    const [playerItem, setPlayerItem] = useState(null)

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <SearchContext.Provider value={searchText}>
        <CatalogueSearchContext.Provider value={searchText}>
        <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ playerItem, setPlayerItem }}>
        <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/tier_a" element={<TierA/>}/>
                    <Route path="/tier_b" element={<TierB/>}/>
                    <Route path="catalogue"> 
                        <Route index element={<Catalogue/>}/>
                        <Route path="search" element={<CatalogueSearch />}/>
                        <Route path="posts" element={<Post/>}/>  
                        <Route path="post/:id" element={<PostDetail />}/>
                        <Route path="people" element={<People />}/>
                        <Route path="chapters" element={<Chapters />}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin/>}/>
                    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </PlayerContext.Provider>
        </CatalogueSearchContext.Provider>
        </SearchContext.Provider>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}


export default App;
```

Getting the following error when trying to hit any of the catalogue nested routes like `/catalogue/posts` or `/catalogue/people`:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(PostDetail)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(PostDetail) in connect options.
    at ConnectFunction (connect.js:244:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:20387:1)
    at updateSimpleMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:20222:1)
    at updateMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:20081:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22502:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
```

My question is do i need to move the `Catalogue` code like `useEffect()`, states, contextProviders, to `App.js` for the props to work? `"store"` & etc apply to every catalogue child. I can't put the Provider code in `<Routes> </Routes>` because of the error

```
Error: [Provider] is not a <route> component. all component children of <routes> must be a <route> or <react.fragment>
```

Please advise how to fix. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `Catalogue` component is the component rendering the Redux `Provider` and `Catalogue` is only rendered when the path is `"/catalogue"` as the index route. This means that the Redux `Provider` component and store aren't mounted when rendering any other `"/catalogue/XYZ"` sub-route. The `react-router-dom@6` version of `Catalogue` isn't a true 1-1 conversion.

To fix, `Catalogue` should be converted to a layout route that renders an `Outlet` for its nested routes. `CatalogueHome` is the component that should be rendered on the index route. You will also want to move the Redux store declaration ***outside*** any React component so is isn't redeclared each render cycle.

Example:

Catalogue

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  chapters: playlistReducer,
  people: playlistReducer,
});

const store = createStore(reducers); // <-- declared once

const Catalogue = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className={style.App}>
        <SideBar />
        <CatalogueHeader account={{display_name: "User"}}/>
        <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
        <FooterBar />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Catalogue;
```

App

```
const App = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <SearchContext.Provider value={searchText}>
        <CatalogueSearchContext.Provider value={searchText}>
          <PlayerContext.Provider value={{ playerItem, setPlayerItem }}>
            <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/tier_a" element={<TierA />} />
                <Route path="/tier_b" element={<TierB />} />
                <Route path="catalogue" element={<Catalogue />}> // <-- Catalogue is layout route 
                  <Route
                    index
                    element={(
                      <CatalogueHome // <-- CatalogueHome is index route
                        chapters={chapters}
                        people={people}
                        posts={posts}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                  <Route path="search" element={<CatalogueSearch />} />
                  <Route path="posts" element={<Post />} />  
                  <Route path="post/:id" element={<PostDetail />} />
                  <Route path="people" element={<People />} />
                  <Route path="chapters" element={<Chapters />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
              </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </PlayerContext.Provider>
        </CatalogueSearchContext.Provider>
      </SearchContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```